# MariaDb - How to ensure a (LEFT) JOIN only if a single right side record exists

Tags: mariadb, join

I have two tables I need to join together. However, I only want to join records when there are unqiue matches rather than picking one of several for the join.

## Versioning:

Using MariaDB version 10.3.34

## Example Data:

Core (LEFT) data `towns`

| id | town | postcode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hudderfield | HD11 4ER |
| 2 | Manchester | MN14 3JE |
| 3 | Macklesfield | MK17 9FL |
| 4 | Edinburgh | ED5 3MJ |
| 5 | Liverpool | LV9 8XT |

Joined (RIGHT) data `peoples`:

| id | names | postcode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jimmy Saville | HD11 4ER |
| 2 | Jason Bomb | IP14 8FK |
| 3 | Micky Mouse | MK17 9FL |
| 4 | Bobby Dillian | ED5 3MJ |
| 5 | Lenny Davies | ED5 3MJ |

## My SQL:

My initial query would be something like:

```
SELECT towns.id, towns.town, peoples.name FROM towns 
       LEFT JOIN people ON towns.postcode = peoples.postcode
```

But this will include `Edinburgh` but there are two people in Edinburgh, I only want to join when there's a single unqiue row to join on.

I use LEFT join because I need to return all of `towns` but only the unique rows of `peoples`.

## Expected results:

| id | town | names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hudderfield | Jimmy Saville |
| 2 | Manchester | <null> |
| 3 | Macklesfield | Micky Mouse |
| 4 | Edinburgh | <null> |
| 5 | Liverpool | <null> |

## What I've tried

I've tried using `COUNT()` in the JOIN but can't get this to work,

```
SELECT towns.id, towns.town, peoples.names FROM towns 
       LEFT JOIN people ON towns.postcode = peoples.postcode AND count(peoples.id) = 1
```

Comes up with a syntax error.

I can't think about how I can qualify this join that it only joins when there's a **single** result found. Internet searching gives me lots of far more vague and off topic references.

I'm sure it's simple but I can't do it. Also, I'd like to avoid subquerying if possible?

---

[Database Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/axkxaR2RVzzdMWNE3dWsfL/0)

Comment: What do you want when there are 2 matching rows on the 'right'?

Comment: Not relevant to the technical question, but assuming this is real data (not make believe data created as an example to ask about the concept): in your data those are street (or part-street) level postcodes. You could have many people in the same town with different postcodes, all but the smallest village will have more than one postcode of that length, a town or city will have many. In the past I've lived at YO1 5BQ and YO10 4DL, both in York.

Comment: @DavidSpillett yes this is simply example data for a real issue combining records based on postcode but disallowing multiple records with duplicate postcodes. Also I don't think Jimmy Saville was actually from Huddersfield.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative way to Lennart's window function answer, is to just use a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause against the `peoples` table to filter out the ones with the same `postcode` like so:

```
SELECT towns.id, towns.town, peoples.names
FROM towns
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(names) AS names, postcode
    FROM peoples
    GROUP BY postcode
    HAVING COUNT(name) = 1
) peoples
ON towns.postcode = peoples.postcode
```

Comment: What's the purpose of MAX here?

Comment: When you use a `GROUP BY` clause, you have to use an aggregate function to select columns that aren't being grouped on. In this case, since you only care about the groups that have 1 value in them (i.e. the people with unique post codes) then it doesn't matter which aggregate function you use here, `MAX` or `MIN`, it'll always be the same 1 person.

Comment: I actually removed the `MAX` entirely and the query works without it. MariaDB 10.3.34 My original mistake with `COUNT` was that I'd not put the subquery of the LEFT JOIN in brackets.

Comment: @Martin Yea that's true, in some versions of MySQL and MariaDB, you're technically not *required* to use an aggregate function on the non-grouped fields, which then I believe it picks a value at random (in this case again it wouldn't matter since each grouping only has 1 row / person in it anyway, so same outcome either way). I'm used to Microsoft SQL Server, where it is required to use an aggregate function.

Comment: @SalmanA Please read the previous comments. It is required in some RDBMS such as Microsoft SQL Server. Also, I think it's good habit to do, so you're used to providing intent on what you expect back from the query as opposed to letting it be nondeterministic, which could lead to confusion in the cases where there are multiple rows in the grouping.

Comment: In MySQLit's controlled by the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode. This is off by default pre-5.7, on by default since then. @SalmanA It should be required by any sane RDBM unless `names` is functionally dependent on `postcode`, which it isn't here. While it's true that it's redundant when you specifically restrict to count=1, I don't think the database is required to detect this special case.

Comment: My bad. I now see that names is being used in outermost select so yes, we need people.names which in turn needs to be placed inside max or some other aggregate fn.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to left join peoples with:

```
(select name, postcode
from (
  select name, postcode, count(1) over (partition by postcode) as cnt
  from peoples
) as t
where cnt = 1)
```

i.e.

```
SELECT t.id, t.town, p.name 
FROM towns t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT name, postcode
           FROM (
               SELECT name, postcode
                    , count(1) over (partition by postcode) as cnt
               FROM peoples
           ) as x
           WHERE cnt = 1
) p
    USING (postcode)
```

EDIT:

Given the ddl provided in the update I created the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=f53fbe2ad63ce5a5673d41a3c86ff49d)

```
SELECT t.id, t.town, p.names 
FROM towns t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT names, postcode
    FROM (
       SELECT names, postcode
            , count(1) over (partition by postcode) as cnt
       FROM peoples
    ) as x
    WHERE cnt = 1
) p
    USING (postcode);
```

It appears to give the expected result

Comment: Note: If you want to try the query in your fiddle, you need to change version of MySQL to 8.

Comment: You can avoid a level of nested subqueries by using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.

Comment: Do you mean using a window function in a HAVING clause?

Comment: I mean like J.D.'s answer.

Comment: Yes, then I agree

Answer (score 5):

Even simpler:

```
SELECT t.id, t.town, 
       IF (COUNT(DISTINCT p.names) = 1, MAX(p.names), NULL) AS names
    FROM towns AS t
    LEFT JOIN peoples AS p  ON t.postcode = p.postcode 
    GROUP BY t.id
```

I believe it avoids the "only full group by" issue mentioned in previous Comments.  (If not, see the comments on this Answer.)

Comment: `Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.p.names' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: However adding a `GROUP_CONCAT` or `MAX` on `p.names` will resolve it.

Comment: @jcaron simply adding the `p.names`  field to the group by fixed this for me, I think.

Comment: @Martin - I changed the SQL, check it.

Comment: @Martin it fixes the error but shouldn’t give the result you want (and wouldn’t make much sense since you would have an aggregate function on a field you are grouping by).

Comment: @RickJames no changes to the SQL in your edit.

Comment: @jcaron I did see and trial this answer yesterday and it came up with the group by error and I did mitigate it somehow but I don't remember my actions,  I thought I'd simply added the field to the group part. /shrug.

Comment: @jcaron - I goofed; look again.

Comment: If you add another Micky Mouse in Macklesfield, it will be in the result ( `COUNT(DISTINCT p.names) will still be = 1` ). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=8311b55f7c013f784ab09dead3b8f1b9

Comment: `COUNT(t.postcode)=1` might be an alternative

Answer (score 2):

Look, mum, no subqueries and aggregate or windowing functions!

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.town
     , IF( p2.id IS NOT NULL, NULL, p1.names ) AS names
  FROM towns AS t
  LEFT JOIN peoples AS p1  ON p1.postcode =  t.postcode
  LEFT JOIN peoples AS p2  ON p2.postcode = p1.postcode
                          AND p2.id != p1.id
 GROUP BY t.id
;
```

Comment: gold star for that!!